# Python: ArgParse with a Main command and Sub command

Tags: python, argparse

Hi I'm using ArgParse to handle my arguments. I would like the code to work like this

```
# Main function
$ myApp -i INPUT -o OUTPUT -s STUFF
```

---

```
# Configure function
$ myApp config -a conf1 -b conf2
```

---

```
import argparse
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='myApp',formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter) 
parser.add_argument('-i',help='input',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o',help='output',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-s',help='stuff',default=None,required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

subp = parser.add_subparsers()
conf_parser = subp.add_parser('config', help='configure')
conf_parser.add_argument('-a',help='a config file',default=None,required=False)
conf_parser.add_argument('-b',help='b config file',default=None,required=False)
conf_args = conf_arser.parse_args()
```

Here's the output

```
python sandbox/test1.py  --help
usage: test1.py [-h] -i I -o O [-s S]

myApp

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -i I        input
  -o O        output
  -s S        stuff
```

I'm not getting the config args to show. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solved it

---

```
import argparse
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='myApp',formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-i',help='input',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o',help='output',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-s',help='stuff',default=None,required=False)

subp = parser.add_subparsers(help='configure')
conf_parser = subp.add_parser('config')
conf_parser.add_argument('-a',help='a config file',default=None,required=False)
conf_parser.add_argument('-b',help='b config file',default=None,required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

---

```
python sandbox/test1.py --help
usage: test1.py [-h] -i I -o O [-s S] {config} ...

myApp

positional arguments:
  {config}    configure

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -i I        input
  -o O        output
  -s S        stuff
```

---

```
python sandbox/test1.py config --help
usage: test1.py config [-h] [-a A] [-b B]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a A        a config file
  -b B        b config file
```